# How to add dynamically UI module in android?

Tags: android, xml, design-patterns, fragment

I want to build android app (App1, App2, App3 and etc - Achieve this by product flavors in gradle) from my single source code.
1. App1, App2, App3 and etc has some feature. Functionally same but **UI may different for each Application**
2. Features are module. Feature can be added by gradle scrip (flavor).

My question is, I am ok with functionality. How can i dynamically add UI module?

Comment: Try to make different resource directory for each flavors.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier Functionality may differ each app. Fragment not fixed for all applications. For example Point1) App1 - Screen1 has F1 and F2 feature. Point2) App2 - Screen1 has F1 and Screen2 has F2.

Comment: Same way, you can have the same Fragment, in each flavor but not same the code inside. if you want an example tell me.

Comment: Yes, can you pls share example.

Comment: I want to build application for various client. Above approach will help to build single client with various app. I don't want to build other application source.

Comment: What is the difference between client ?

Comment: I mean the vendor (Multiple vendor).

Comment: Right now, i don't understand, what do you want, because what I give you below, give you multiple application, with multiple layout/fragment different.

Comment: yes i can understand the below solution, If i the build app for Vendor1 it has the Vendor2 and Vendor3 source code. I want to avoid it. Can you get me?

Comment: Yes, I understand, and no, only the code from your flavor and the main app, will be keep. Because, you get some `Duplicate class` they keep them. And you can see in your Android Studio, that only `class` related to flavor selected will appear, the other will not be taken.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136868/discussion-between-ramki-anba-and-raphael-teyssandier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the class will be in each flavor but not in your main app, or you will get a `Duplicate class error`. Same for the layout.

**Gradle**

```
    productFlavors {
        manual_count {
            applicationId "com.example.example.app.manual_count"
        }

        manual_sensor {
            applicationId "com.example.example.app.manual_sensor"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        manual_count {
            res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res', 'src/manual_count/res', 'src/manual_count/res/']
        }

        manual_sensor {
            res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res', 'src/manual_sensor/res', 'src/manual_sensor/res/']
        }
    }
```

**ProjectStructure**

[image]

To do that:

- Right click on your flavor directory then `New` -> `Folder` -> `Java Folder` -> `Finish` (Inside, you will put your code Fragment)
- Right click on your flavor directory then `New` -> `Folder` -> `Res Folder` -> Enable `Change Folder Location` -> `Finish`
- Make sure to add the main res directory in your `sourceSets` (see example below)
- Create `layout`, `values`, etc... by doing : Right click on your res flavor directory -> `New` -> `Directory` -> Put the name of the resources directory (`layout`, `values`, ...)
- Create your layout file, right click on `layout` directory -> `New` -> `Layout resources File`